# Installing/Using tenserflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, spyder

I am getting this error when trying to import tensorflow:

> File "/Users/alexkaram/untitled3.py", line 7, in 
> import tensorflow as tf
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

My Spyder version is 5.3.3 and anaconda navigator 2.3.1.

I tried to install tensorflow but am unsure if I was successful.

I tried the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install have you run any of installation commands? `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: I have tried conda install theano
conda install tensorflow
conda install keras and the environments have failed, I will try those now

Comment: after those commands, my terminal is still examining conflicts, its at 99/440

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a big fan of anaconda, probably the issue is with your anaconda installation.